# PHP: copy() is messing up file permissions somehow

Tags: php, apache, ftp

I have an image uploader on my site...

The image is uploaded to a temporary 777 folder (this image works fine and can be deleted), I then copy this file into a new dir with `copy()` the new file is written to a 777 folder, but cannot be deleted. `chmod()` doesn't seem to help...

Why does the `copy()` function create the new file somehow different to the original file? I can't see any differences in my FTP client. BOTH have perms 644 and user 'nobody/99' - but it's only a problem for the second file.

Any ideas?

Comment: maybe there's an alternative function i can use to `copy()` ?

Comment: The file permissions do not affect whether or not you can unlink the file. You need write access to the directory to unlink the file. Double check your directory permissions.

Comment: @bert - the directories are fine i can create and delete files in them. the issue is the copy()...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue was the parent folder.

I needed to `chmod()` the parent folder, even though i had made it wit `777` perms....

Comment: Don't use 777, that makes me a sad panda. There should never ever be a need for 777 on a decently configured server.

Answer (score 3):

You need to manually set the permissions bits yourself: try this.

```
copy($temp_img_url, $save_file_as); chmod($save_file_as, fileperms($temp_img_url));
```

Comment: Thanks Femi, but this still sets perms to 644 and user to nobody/99. I think the problem is with the user not the perms?

Comment: Ah: user in general must match the user the web server is running as, which I'm guessing is nobody with group id 99. There is a `chown` function (see http://php.net/manual/en/function.chown.php) that will change the owner of a file, but typically you have to be root to do that. Try it and see if it works. The other option might be to use a shell and do a `cp -a $temp_img_url $save_file_as` and see if that preserves ownership/file attributes, but once again your mileage may vary depending on the permissions available to the user the web server is running as.

Answer (score 2):

Because `copy()` makes a new COPY of the file. Only its contents will stay the same. Permissions of the new file are controlled by your script's `umask()` setting, and the new filename is controlled by you.

Comment: thanks - i see the example here (http://php.net/manual/en/function.umask.php), but am not sure how i'm meant to implement it?

Comment: The umask represents bits to disable on new files' permissions. If you set umask to 0, then no permissions are disabled. The calculation is done `(new file's permissions) and (not (umask))` to get the new file's permission bits. So setting a mask of 0 gets inverted to 0xFF and anded with the other value, returning the original value.

Comment: so i shoudld do this? `umask(0);
copy($temp_img_url, $save_file_as); `(i'm not considerring security at this point)